# How to create array of strings in winapi

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

I try this

```
LPWSTR* arrayM = new LPWSTR[150];
```

Does not work

```
for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    array[i] = new char[13];
    swprintf(array[i], str, i);
}
```

Thanks much in advance!!!

Comment: is `arrayM` a typo, that should just be `array`?

Comment: If you want to use strings, why not use strings?

Answer (score 2):

`LPWSTR` is a wide string, so is `swprintf`.

Therefore, you want

```
array[i] = new wchar_t[13];
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will allocate a string array.

```
char** slist = new char*[10];
for (int i = 0; i++; i < 10)
{
    slist[i] = new char[10];
}

//after using the string list, free them

for (int i = 0; i++; i < 10)
{
   delete   slist[i];
}

delete slist;
```

Or if you can use std, you can just use: `vector<string>`